# Can we add a Flutter module to an existing Android Studio project?

Tags: android, flutter

I have been reading about [Flutter](https://flutter.io/) for a while now, and I want to convert parts of my app to learn more. I have an existing Android project written in Java/Kotlin. Is it possible to add a new Flutter module to the existing app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can embed a `FlutterView` into an existing android or ios project. To have a part of your view using flutter, you can take a look at flutter view example [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/flutter_view). For switching between fullscreen android and flutter views, you can look into [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/platform_view) example.

Hope that helped!